# Unwanted conversion from Scala AnyVal types to Java Types

Tags: java, scala

I'm writing a function that get some parameters and extract their types, but whenever this parameters are under Scala AnyVal (Int, Long, Double, ...) they get converted to Java Types (Integer, ...).

Here a small example of that function:

```
def functionX(args: Any*) = {
   args.map(a => a.getClass)
}

val num: Int = 10

println(num1.getClass) // prints int

println(functionX(num1)) // prints Integer
```

**What should I do to have all parameters types, whether they're Int or Integer, in their original types and not converted?**

I also realized that if a variable is put inside a Scala collection, it also gets converted to Java types:

```
val num: Int = 1
val numList = List(num)

println(num.getClass) // prints int
println(numList.head.getClass) // prints Integer
```

Is there any Java autoboxing happening? But aren't Scala types, like Int, under AnyVal class and nor primitive types?

---

To give more context on why I'm trying to do this, here is an example:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def myTraitMethod : String
}

object MyObj extends MyTrait {
  def myTraitMethod = "Works fine"
  def myObjMethod(num1: Int, num2: Int) = num1 * num2
}

case object Manager {
  def currentObj: MyTrait = MyObj
}

val result = Manager.currentObj.myObjMethod
// I wanted to access this object method that is not in Trait, but
// it doesn't seem possible.
```

Instead of doing the last line of the code above, I'm using Reflection to do something like this:

```
def executeMethod(obj: MyTrait, methodName: String, args: Any*) = {
    val argTypes = args.map(t => t.getClass)
    val argsObjects = args.map(o => o.asInstanceOf[Object])

    val method = obj.getClass.getMethod(methodName, argTypes:_*)

    method.invoke(obj, argsObjects:_*)

}

val num = 10
val result = executeMethod(Manager.currentObj, "myObjMethod", num1, num2)
// That's where I have problem with Int being converted to Integer
// and the method is not found because it's (Int, Int) and not (Integer, Integer)
```

Comment: compile-time Scala types and runtime Java classes are different things. On the language level we only have objects _(e.g. **Int**)_ but the runtime world is a different thing, when running on the JVM _(remember Scala may be run on ther platforms like JS)_ we have objects and primitives, but you can not ask for the class of a primitive, thus an auto-boxing is applied. Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Why is working with `Any` if `AnyVal` is expected?

Comment: @cchantep Because this function could get Objects as parameters as well, like `DataFrame`.

Comment: `Any` is generally a symptom of design issue

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This is a workaround for a problem that I've faced while trying to access a method in an object that is not in the Trait it extends. So, I'm trying to build a generic function that allows that, by getting the object, the method's name and its parameters and executing the method through Reflection. Do you see a better way to do that?

Comment: @HissashiRocha It would be good if you can explain all that with details on the question. Which object, which trait, what do you control, what you don't.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've added more details on why I'm trying to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @HissashiRocha You didn't specify which of those you control _(meaning you can modify)_. But in general, if you need to access an implementation detail behind an abstraction, then such abstraction is a failed one.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez well, the abstraction works fine for most of my needs, because, in order to be used, it just need to implement one main method (that may call others that are not in the Trait). The problem is when I'm creating unit tests for those methods (those that are specified by the trait and those that are not, because some of them are particular to each object).

Comment: @HissashiRocha If this is just for unit testing, then there are two general ideas for this kind of cases. One is an idea that you should not test private behaviors, as such you should only test the public API _(which transitively would test the private methods)_ - On the other hand, there is an argument that for doing proper unit testing, you should test those methods too, an usual workaround is to make them `private[package]` so your tests can access them without the need of reflection.

Comment: @HissashiRocha You have an instance of a trait and you want to call a method that's not a member of the trait. That means you know that the object is an instance of some *other* class, the one that has this method. Could you just cast the object to that class and then call the method?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I thought about casting but there isn't another class, only this trait. It's just possible for objects to implement particular methods in my code (is it a bad thing?).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'll think about that and I'll check this workaround as well. Thanks!

Comment: @HissashiRocha Try this: `Manager.currentObj.asInstanceOf[MyObj.type].myObjMethod(2, 3)`

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I was kinda trying to avoid this approach because I didn't want anyone, except for the "Manager", to know which was the  _currentObj_. If I do this, every time someone changes the "current" object in the Manager, it would have to change it in the tests as well. Anyway, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @HissashiRocha Wouldn't this be true even if the test calls the method using reflection? If someone changes `currentObj` they'd have to change the test too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`functionX` is a function that takes a variable number of arguments of type `Any`.

At some point, Scala is going to have to compile this into a function that can run on the JVM. That function is going to take one argument, which will be an array or sequence type, because that's how the JVM implements variable arguments. In fact, it's going to be `scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq`.

You probably understand that JVM primitive types are not objects. You can't have a single variable that can either hold a primitive value like `int` *or* an object like `String`. The JVM includes "box" types `Integer`, `Double`, etc., so you can use primitive values as objects when necessary.

`ArraySeq` has to be an collection of something, and since in the case of `functionX` you've said that it can hold anything, at the JVM level, the something has to be `Object`. Since it's an `ArraySeq` of `Object`, any primitive values that you want to put into it will have to be boxed.

All the behavior you observe will make sense once you realize that Scala's `Int` type is the JVM's primitive `int` type. They're not really objects.

In order to invoke the right method through reflection, you could just assume that if an argument is of type `Integer`, then you should use the type `Integer.TYPE` or `classOf[int]` for the purpose of looking up the method. Of course that will fail if the method you want actually takes `Integer`. Once you find the right method, the JVM will take care of unboxing any boxed values in your argument list.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now. Thanks for sharing this! I'll think of an alternative for that.